# Wget using Termux download directory

Tags: downloading, command-line, termux

I just installed Wget using Termux on my Android. But, when I download a file, I cannot find it's location. Can anyone please tell me where it's located? And how can I change that location to my desired directory?

Comment: `wget` usually downloads to where you called it from – unless told otherwise using the `-O` parameter. So you either first `cd` to the desired directory – or try something like `wget -O /sdcard/downloads/foo.zip http://example.com/foo.zip`.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I'm not rooted. So, is there any way that would allow me to delete the file or at least copy or move it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote Izzy,

> `wget` usually downloads to where you called it from – unless told
>   otherwise using the `-O` parameter. So you either first `cd` to the
>   desired directory – or try something like `wget -O
>   /sdcard/downloads/foo.zip http://example.com/foo.zip`.

In your case, this directory is **/data/data/com.termux/files/home** and, as it's inside **/data**, only root and the files' owner can alter things here.

Since Termux is the owner, though, you can move, copy and delete files and folders inside the abovementioned directory.

---

### Before moving or copying to the internal storage

If you run Android Marshmallow (6.x) or above, run `termux-setup-storage` and grant the requested permission to be able to interact with anything inside **/storage/emulated/0**.

---

### To move files

To move files to e.g. the standard download directory, use the command `mv source destination`, replacing `source` with the file you wish to move, and `destination` with `/storage/emulated/0/Download`, which is the default download directory located in your internal storage.

---

### To copy files

To copy files to e.g. the standard download directory, use the command `cp source destination`, replacing `source` with the file you wish to move, and `destination` with `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.

---

### To delete files

To delete any file, use `rm file`, replacing `file` with the file you wish to delete.

---

### To delete directories

To delete an empty directory, use `rmdir directory`.

To delete a non-empty directory, use `rm -r directory`. *This method will delete anything inside the chosen directory.*

In both cases, replace `directory` with the directory you wish to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Type `echo $HOME` in Termux. That is the current wget location.

[image]

Comment: The HOME variable does not reflect the current location. If OP `cd`ed somewhere else, `echo $HOME` would've shown `/data/data/com.termux/files/home` nonetheless, thus giving a correct result to a wrong question. To know the current directory, use either `pwd` or `echo $PWD`.

Comment: Yap wget works at working directory. However the screenshot is valid :D